# Searching one collection by a value in another, in Meteor (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm building a Twitter clone, and I've hit a wall with sorting.

Here are my collections:

```
Tweets:
  createdAt: Date
  body:      String
  userId:    String

Events:
  createdAt: Date
  type:      String (either 'retweet' or 'like')
  tweetId:   String
  userId:    String
```

When a user clicks 'retweet', it creates a new `Event` document which tracks the tweet and user IDs.

Then, when I view a user's profile page, I do a search for all Tweets either composed by the user, or where a 'retweet' Event exists with that user Id. I do a reactive join on the server so that the `Tweets` collection has all the necessary tweets.

The problem is sorting: I'm sorting all Tweets by their `createdAt` value. If I retweet a Tweet that was created yesterday, it'll show up in my feed *below* any of my own tweets in the last day.

In other words, I need a way to sort Tweets either by their own `createdAt` field, *or* by the `createdAt` field of an associated Event if such a thing exists.

---

I'm not opposed to restructuring my models if there's a better way to do this. I had thought about creating a new Tweet whenever you 'retweet', but the problem is that each Tweet has a `likeCount` and a `retweetCount`. If I create a brand new Tweet whenever it's retweeted, and someone likes or retweets the retweet, all the numbers would be wrong (or there would be an absurd amount of denormalizing-updating required).

Comment: Seems the easiest way would be to add a `tweetedAt` date field on Tweets. Otherwise sorting will be very slow as you'll need to map your tweets and augment them with the `Event.createdAt` date.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Michel! Not entirely sure what you mean though; tweets already have a `createdAt` date field when they're tweeted. The problem is a given tweet might be re-tweeted 1000 times, each time with a different date tied to a specific user.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. Do you always have an `Event` even for the original? In which case you can just order Events by their `createdAt` date and lookup the tweet content for each event.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't =(. I suppose I could create one, just to make my life easier. How would I sort the `Tweets` collection by the `Events` collection, then? I could `.fetch()` them on the client and use `_.sortBy`, but is there a better way on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you always create an `event` for each tweet
2. Use the [reywood:publish-composite]https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package to publish the `Events` collection sorted by the `Event.createdAt` key and limited to however many events you want to show.
3. In your template, do `{{#each events}}` instead of `{{each tweets}}`
4. Use a template helper to return the body of the tweet

Helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  events: function(){
    return Events.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  body: function(){
    return Tweets.findOne({ _id: this.tweetId }).body;
  }
});
```

This would be a normalized approach. For performance and given that tweets are short you can just copy the `body` field from each tweet into the `Events` document.